# Regexp, force text vertical

Tags: c#, regex

i have this text:"i like stackoverflow", and want this result with regexp (separated with `\n`):

```
i
l
i
k
e
s
....
```

how i can do that with c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not sure regex is ideal for this (see [Donut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349192/regexp-force-text-vertical/4349229#4349229)), but if you really want one...

```
Regex.Replace("i like stackoverflow", "([^\\s]\\s?)", "$1\n");
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a regex for this, you can just do this:

```
string input = "i like stackoverflow";

string result = string.Join("\n", input.Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray());
```

This code does the following:

1. Removes all spaces in your string (`input.Replace(" ", "")`)
2. Splits the string into a character array (`.ToCharArray()`).
3. Joins the elements in the character array back into a single string, with a newline character separating each of them (`string.Join("\n", ...)`)

Regular expressions are incredibly useful when their use is warranted. When it's not, though, keep this [jwz quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) in mind:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think the regex you're looking for is

`(a-zA-Z)`

replace with

`$1\n`

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(yourstring, ".\\s?", m => m.Value + Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

### rot90

If you can translate this to C♯, I think it may do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
# rot90 
# Tom Christiansen <tchrist@perl.com>

$/ = "";

# uncomment for easier to read, but not reversible:
### @ARGV = map { "fmt -20 $_ |" } @ARGV;

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    @lines = split /\n/;
    $MAXCOLS = -1;
    for (@lines) { $MAXCOLS = length if $MAXCOLS < length; }
    @vlines = ( " " x @lines ) x $MAXCOLS;
    for ( $row = 0; $row < @lines; $row++ ) {
        for ( $col = 0; $col < $MAXCOLS; $col++ ) {
            $char = ( length($lines[$row]) > $col  )
                    ? substr($lines[$row], $col, 1) 
                    : ' ';
            substr($vlines[$col], $row, 1) = $char;
        }
    }
    for (@vlines) {
        # uncomment for easier to read, but again not reversible
        s/(.)/$1 /g;
        print $_, "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

It doesn't use any regular expressions, so I would think translate would be possible.

Given this sample input:

```
I sit beside the
fire and think
of all that
I have seen:
of butterflies
and meadowflowers
and places
that I've been.
I sit beside the
fire and think
of how the world
shall be
when winter comes
without a spring
that I shall
ever see.
```

it produces this output file:

```
I f o I o a a t I f o s w w t e 
  i f   f n n h   i f h h i h v 
s r   h   d d a s r   a e t a e 
i e a a b     t i e h l n h t r 
t   l v u m p   t   o l   o     
  a l e t e l I   a w   w u I s 
b n     t a a ' b n   b i t   e 
e d t s e d c v e d t e n   s e 
s   h e r o e e s   h   t a h . 
i t a e f w s   i t e   e   a   
d h t n l f   b d h     r s l   
e i   : i l   e e i w     p l   
  n     e o   e   n o   c r     
t k     s w   n t k r   o i     
h         e   . h   l   m n     
e         r     e   d   e g     
          s             s
```

Hope this helps! If you do translate it into C♯, I’d love it if you’d mail me a copy, because I’m curious how it works there.  I only know Java(*), not C♯, and have heard it’s a lot nicer. Then again, so is a boot to the head. :)

---

- I don’t mean I Java is the only language I know. I’ve worked in BASIC-PLUS, FORTRAN, Pascal, Modula-2, PDP-11 assembler, C, C⁺⁺, DCL, Exec8, Ada, Lisp, Scheme, Prolog, Ratfor, Shell, Icon, REXX, Awk, Perl, Python, M4, Tcl, Ruby, Java, Go, and maybe a dozen little languages of my own devising.  Plus I’m sure I’ve forgotten some.  I just don’t know C♯.  Please forgive me.  I hope my code can still help you.